# Specification and XML parsing with lot of entities -> out of memory error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a request to find a lot of entities in my database with a Specification.

After gettin`g them I ne`ed to parse them into another entity in order to export them into a XML file. When my Specification get to much entities (~6 000) I get an out of memory error.

Does anyone have a solution ? I'm out of ideas ...(increase heap size is not an option)

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/cmc")
public String getXmlExport(CmcCriteria cmcCriteria, Model model) throws CmcCommonsException {

    Specification<Cmc> cmcSpec = cmcService.getSpec(cmcCriteriaResource);
    List<Cmc> cmcList = cmcRepository.findAll(cmcSpec);

    model.addAttribute("requestCmcXml", getCmcXmlListFromCmcList(cmcList));
    return "cmc/list";
}


@Override
protected final void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    List<CmcXml> listeCmcXml = (List<CmcXml>) model.get("requestCmcXml");

    CmcXmlExport export = new CmcXmlExport();
    export.setPersonnels(listeCmcXml);
    response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE_XML);
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CmcXmlExport.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(export, out);
    out.flush();

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "CMC")
public class CmcXmlExport {

    private List<CmcXml> personnels;
    [...]
}

@XmlType(propOrder = { "id", "nom", "prenom", "genre", [...] })
public class CmcXml implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String genre;
[...]
}
```

Comment: *"increase heap size is not an option"* Why is that so? If your 6000 entities need to much space it might be the only valid option. Or to load less data. Can you provide the error output?

Comment: Could I just check that you are using the term "entities" in its correct XML sense (typically something referenced by `&name;`) and that it's not a typo for "elements"? I ask because people don't usually hold XML entities in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Apache Xerces lib for Java: [Official website](https://xerces.apache.org/). It encourages to write more efficient code for XML parcing and handling.

This lib provides you the methods for handling XML blocks and you will have to write some additional code that parse your entities.